# Can I create an Airtable view containing records not present in a "linked records" column?

Tags: filtering, airtable

I have a table with columns like:

```
Name (Single Line Text) | Partner (Link to "Name")
----------------------- | --------------------------
John Doe                | `Jane Doe`
Jane Doe                | (Empty)
Bob Smith               | `Mary Smith` `Kevin Smith`
Mary Smith              | (Empty)
Kevin Smith             | (Empty)
Alan Stephens           | (Empty)
```

I'd like to create a new view for this table with filtering like:

```
WHERE {Partner (field)} is not empty
OR {Partner (column)} does not contain {Name}
```

such that the result would be:

```
Name (Single Line Text) | Partner (Link to "Name")
----------------------- | --------------------------
John Doe                | `Jane Doe`
Bob Smith               | `Mary Smith` `Kevin Smith`
Alan Stephens           | (Empty)
```

The challenge here is that on line 1 of my filter, I'm looking for "records with no records linked in their `Partner` column", but on line 2 I'm looking for "records which are not found in the `Partner` column for any other record".

The overall goal is to generate a list of records with no `Partner`(s) *plus* records who are not anyone else's `Partner`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that a filter such as this one is outside the available feature set of Airtable. I was able to implement a workaround:

1. Add a Script block containing the script described in [this video](https://community.airtable.com/t/new-script-same-table-linked-records-backlinks/28120) ([script gist](https://gist.github.com/on2air/b68450a877ab99fe4a93ef7f9c387568))
2. Use the Script block to populate a new column on the table (`Partner Of`)

```
Name (Single Line Text) | Partner (Link to "Name")   | Partner Of (Link to "Name")
----------------------- | -------------------------- | ---------------------------
John Doe                | `Jane Doe`                 | (Empty)
Jane Doe                | (Empty)                    | `John Doe`
Bob Smith               | `Mary Smith` `Kevin Smith` | (Empty)
Mary Smith              | (Empty)                    | `Bob Smith`
Kevin Smith             | (Empty)                    | `Bob Smith`
Alan Stephens           | (Empty)                    | (Empty)
```

3. Create a new view with a filter like:

```
WHERE {Partner Of} is empty
```